# Is it possible that the halting problem is solvable for all input except the machine's code?

Tags: computability, undecidability, halting-problem

This question occurred to me about the halting problem and I couldn't find a good answer online, wondering if someone can help.

Is it possible that the halting problem is decidable for any TM on any input so long as the input is not the TM itself? Basically:

```
Halts(TM, I)
    IF TM == I:
        Undecidable, return a random result/throw an exception, whatever
    ELSE:
        Solve the problem

Halts'(X)
    IF Halts(X, X):
        Loop infinitely
    ELSE:
        Print 'done'
```

This seemingly resolves the contradiction. When we call the paradoxical Halts'(Halts'), we can't expect consistent behavior, but all other calls to Halts (and Halts') are legitimate and solvable.

I understand that this is highly unintuitive. If some pattern in the bits could reveal the behavior of all possible programs, why would it suddenly fall apart when the TM and input match? But can we mathematically eliminate this as a possibility?

And this reduced halting problem would not be uninteresting at all. Even if there were some meaningful program that took its own code as input it could trivially be rewritten to work on slightly different input. Of course this suggestion makes it even less understandable why a halting solution could exist with this one caveat but again, can we really mathematically eliminate this possibility?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Decidability is not affected by finite changes. ​ ​

Comment: there are an infinite # of equivalent TMs, and there is no _(decidable)_ way to detect equivalent TMs (ie its essentially the same as the halting problem itself). however there are some complex "loopholes"; try [chat] for further analysis of the halting problem related to automated thm proving etc... might try to cook this into an answer...

Comment: Touched up my question to be a little clearer, sorry if I mislead anyone.

Comment: The answer is no, as in this answer http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/are-there-any-proofs-the-undecidability-of-the-halting-problem-that-does-not-dep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But we can easily get round your restriction. Suppose a program $G$ that reverses the bits of the input and calls your $H'$ on the result, then define $!H$ with all bits reversed (i.e. 0 for 1s, 1s for 0s). Then we can call your $H'$ with $G(!H)$ and we're back to the original problem.

Comment: Thank you. After reading @David Richerby's answer I started thinking that this is the answer. If we can _construct_ a functionally equivalent Q' for all programs Q, then we can once again decide haltability for **all** problems, not just the ones off the diagonal. I see this is what you're saying.

Answer (score 14):

Recall the standard proof of the undecidability of the halting problem. Suppose that some machine $H$ decides the halting problem and let $Q$ be the machine that, on input $\langle M\rangle$ uses $H$ to determine if $M(\langle M\rangle)$ halts and, if so, $Q$ loops; otherwise, $Q$ halts. Now, $Q(\langle Q\rangle)$ halts if, and only if, it doesn't halt.

> Is it possible that the halting problem is decidable for any TM on any input so long as the input is not the TM itself?

No. If you change the definition of the halting problem in this way, the proof still works. We don't care what happens when $H$ receives $\langle H\rangle$ as input because the contradiction comes after we give input $\langle Q\rangle, \langle Q\rangle$ to $H$.

Second, if you modified $H$ to detect *that* input, we could get the same contradiction by using any other machine $Q'$ that is equivalent to $Q$ in the sense that, for any input $w$, $Q'(w)$ halts if, and only if, $Q(w)$ halts. There are infinitely many of these and $H$ can't detect all of them because it's undecidable whether two Turing machines are equivalent.

Comment: The last paragraph alone may be enough to answer the question: you can not hardcode away all encodings of equivalent machines no matter which finite adaption (based on semantics) you want to perform. (That is not to say that the rest of your post isn't worthwhile reading!)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Isn't the undecidability of whether or not programs are functionally equivalent itself derived from the undecidability of the halting problem? Why would this not be circular reasoning?

Comment: @CS101: the undecidability of $\mathrm{HALT}$ is a theorem once and for all, we aren't "cheating" when we use it to show that it is impossible to solve *another* problem $\mathrm{HALT'}$ which tries to get around the restriction. As a side note, we do know *pragmatically* how to prove termination or non-termination of many *practical* programs (just not all programs). However, proving equivalence of programs turns out to be significantly harder *in practice* (even though they are both undecidable).

Comment: Confused myself, forgot the full halting problem is still the same per my conjecture. Thanks.